# What is a “weak framework reference”?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

What does it mean to have a weak reference to a framework in iphone sdk?

Comment: Are you asking what a 'weak reference' is?  Give some more context to your question.

Comment: If you just Google your question you would find this as the top result: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Comment: @MStodd:you're right, sorry.. I wanted to know what is a weak framework reference and when should I use this kind of reference.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the link, I google it but I didn't get that link. The reason should be that the header Question is not the one I've asked, it was probably changed by some kind of moderator =D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice, if you build an app with a required reference to a framework, rather than a weak reference, and try to run that app on a device which doesn't include that framework, the app with crash, even if you don't try to use that framework.

If, however, you build an app with a weak reference to a framework, and run it on a device that does not support that framework, and do not access classes (methods, subroutines, etc.) in that framework (because you, say, run-time tested for the existence of that framework beforehand) then your app will not simply crash on startup.  But since the framework is weakly linked, you could call that framework from that same app on a device which supported that framework.  Thus your app might support different OS versions with and without support for a given framework.

There might also be some performance differences in start up time causing apps with weak references to launch much slower.

Comment: Do you have a reference for benchmarks on the startup time being slower due to weak linking?  I specifically asked Apple engineers about this at WWDC and they knew of no such slowdown.  I have not observed it in my own applications.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer... and I didn't notice the performance differences in start up either.